# OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

When i run the below command

```
$ docker container exec -it nginx1 ping nginx2
```

This is the error which i faced :

> OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"ping\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

**How to resolve this issue ?**

Comment: Install `ping` into the `nginx1` image during build?

Comment: I didn't install during the build but what i did is after running the container as it was saying exec: \"ping\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown i installed ping inside the container but was of no use \

Comment: How *exactly* did you do this, and how you tried to verify the installation? If the binary *is* installed in the running container and *is* in PATH, it shoud work.

Comment: Firstly i entered the container using docker exec -it bash container_id and installed package manager then i installed ping the installation was successfull then after i tried this command once again  ``` docker container exec -it nginx1 ping nginx2 ```

Comment: Did you try invoking `ping` directly after installing it (not leaving the shell)? If yes did you try it by specifying the full path to the binary (e.g. /usr/bin/ping)?

Comment: `docker exec -it bash container_id` - maybe `docker exec -it container_id bash`? Command goes after container ID.

Comment: You should install ```apt-get install inetutils-ping``` inside your container.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Before reading this answer just let you know, it's my 2nd day of learning docker, It may not be the perfect help for you.

This error may also occur when the ping package is not installed in the container, I resolved the problem as follow, bash into the container like this

```
docker container exec -it my_nginx /bin/bash
```

then install ping package

```
apt-get update
apt-get install inetutils-ping
```

This solved my problem.

Comment: I even specified `nginx:latest` when creating new containers but it definitely needs inetutils-ping package for both containers. Oh, I'd just realized it has to be `nginx:alpine` image and the ping installation is not necessary.

Answer (score 8):

**Please use alpine image of nginx:**

`docker container run -d --name my_nginx_name nginx:alpine`

`docker container run -d --name my_nginx_name2 nginx:alpine`

**Then try to ping using below command:**

`docker container exec -it my_nginx_name ping my_nginx_name2`

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and managed to solve it by accessing:

```sh
docker exec -ti <CONTAINER ID> /bin/sh
```

Comment: It's not an answer to question. Also, not all containers does have `/bin/sh`, so your solution not so general.

Comment: @Yasen `/bin/sh` usually points to the shell the containers is running [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5725402/2445763)

Answer (score 3):

This something I came across recently. When ran a docker container with a custom name and if we put an command/option(s)/etc after the name, that would be passed to the container as commands. So in here container tried to find the ping command inside it but couldn't, So as the above answer you must install the `inetutils-ping` inside the container and run the command

Answer (score 3):

Try this it worked for me

```
# $ docker container exec -it new_nginx bash 
# apt-get update
# apt-get install inetutils-ping
```

Do it for both the container than run your command

```
# $ docker container exec -it nginx1 ping nginx2
```

Answer (score 3):

Install ping utilities in the container .

```
docker container exec -it webhost /bin/bash
apt-get update
apt-get install inetutils-ping

docker container exec -it webhost ping new_nginx
```

Comment: Very nice answer, but I get error:  `E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)`  How do I become superuser insie docker container ? Creds ?

Comment: In order to be a root inside the docker container, break into it like this:
`docker exec -u 0 -it containerName bash`
i.e. with user 0 (-u 0) specification.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install ping in both conatiners,

apt-get update,

apt-get install inetutils-ping

After that Try the ping command.

Answer (score 0):

This error is reported when you try to run the command not found in docker `image`. Please check if `ping` is installed in the `docker` `image`.

Comment: Even if is not installed i tried to install it inside the container using bash but it didn't work

Comment: First run `apt-get update` then try to install `apt-get install inetutils-ping`.